# Is it important to show order receipt every time?

Tags: enterprise, order

Can anybody tell me how important is to show the order receipt every time, whenever the order is placed. Is there any other way to cut off this step? We are handling large enterprise applications where in users buy & provision services using this application.

Answer (score 1):

### YES

Giving order receipt is a **MUST** for any transaction, more so for an enterprise application. In fact, you can be in legal trouble if the customer is not given his order receipt. For enterprise applications, it's also used by employees/users to reimburse the amount from the company if they paid it from their pocket. Some companies mail the receipts instead of showing it to you after completing the transaction. In my opinion, both should be done -- Show the receipt after payment and also mail a copy to the user.

Comment: Most welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

No process is complete without an acknowledgment at the completion.

In this case, the customer performs a transaction involving money. It is mandatory that an acknowledgement in the form of a receipt is shown to the user. Also it will save your customers some anxiety trying to figure out if their order was successfully processed. Besides, the receipt is a good place to show reference information to track down purchase.

Hope this helps.